# how to get a value in select option from database based on id

Tags: php, database, select

I'm trying to get a value from database to select option based on the clicked data

```
`(select * from tabble where id ="")`
```

like that, but i cant delete my query in the select option.

```
<select name="provinsi_dom" id="provinsi_dom">
    <?php
        //mengambil nama-nama provinsi yang ada di database
        $sqlProvinsi_dom = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM provinsi ORDER BY nama_provinsi ASC");
        echo "<option value=''>--<?php echo $provinsi;?>--</option>";
        while($p=mysqli_fetch_array($sqlProvinsi_dom)){
            if ($p['id_provinsi']==$provinsi_dom) {
                $cek="selected";
            }else {
                $cek="";
            }
            echo "<option value='$p[id_provinsi]' $cek>$p[nama_provinsi] </option> " ;  
        }
    ?>
    </select>
```

That is my select option code, i tried to put `<?php echo $provinsi;?>-` in the value but it wont show anything. The data that is shown must from the database based on the clicked id

Answer (score 0):

Dont make it too complex

Just do it on easy way

```
<select name="provinsi_dom" id="provinsi_dom">

    <?php

        $sqlProvinsi_dom = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM provinsi ORDER BY nama_provinsi ASC");
        while($p=mysqli_fetch_array($sqlProvinsi_dom))
        {    
    ?>
    <option <?php if($p['id_provinsi']==$provinsi_dom)echo "selected";?> value="<?=$p[id_provinsi]?>"><?=$p[nama_provinsi]?> </option>
    <?php } ?>
</select>
```

Comment: your seems to show every data on the provinsi table, i want to show only the data that is inserted right now

Comment: didn't understand. explain more by updating question.